# PHP find which days the US Stock market is closed

Tags: php

I started writing a function in PHP to find which days are a holiday.
 I then noticed that these days change from year to year and are not on a fixed day.
I therefore am having trouble writing a function to calculate these days without scraping to find the exact date.

for example:

```
HOLIDAY                         2016                                        2017
New Years Day                   January 1                                   January 1 (Observed Monday, January 2)
Martin Luther King, Jr. Day     January 18                                  January 16
Washington's Birthday           February 15                                 February 20
Good Friday                     March 25                                    April 14
Memorial Day                    May 30                                      May 29
Independence Day                July 4                                      July 4**
Labor Day                       September 5                                 September 4
Thanksgiving Day                November 24*                                November 23*
Christmas                       December 25 (Observed Monday, December 26)  December 25
```

[source](https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars)

Comment: Some holidays are always on the same day, like New Years Day. All others have certain calculation methods like Martin Luther King, Jr. Day, which is always on the 3rd Monday in the month of January. For those days you'll need to write a function.

Comment: with PHP for Martin Luther King, Jr. Day a simple `strtotime('third monday of january' . $year)`will do the job. http://at1.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907561/how-to-get-date-for-holidays-using-php

Comment: @mazedllx see: even new year's day is observed on jan 2 in 2017

Comment: So if new years day falls on a sunday, monday will be a holiday, that's the meaning of observed holiday, isn't it?